# Issues creating an OpenShift Image-stream to a remote container repository

Tags: openshift, imagestream

I am trying to create an image-stream resource within an Red Hat OpenShift cluster via the `oc` command line tool. The source image is contained within an IBM Cloud container repository based in the UK. I have tried to create the image-stream on two different OpenShift clusters, one on IBM's Cloud (but in a different account to the source image), and one hosted in a local data center. Both fail with an authentication error.

However, I am able to deploy the source image as a pod via a deployment file, with a correct image pull-secret. I have also added this working image pull-secret to a number of service-accounts, i.e. deployer, builder, default. But still cannot create the image-stream (or tag the image).

I can however, create an image-stream from a source image also on IBM's Cloud repo, but hosted within the same account as the cluster (so know the command & process work).

Seems the base image-import is not finding my image-pull secret for the remote registry.

Any ideas?

As detailed above tried, on a number of clusters, and repos.